# Display filters being applied on multiple graphs in one place

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter, dc.js

I have multiple charts for which I want to display all filters that are applied. Here is an example of displaying filters for each chart individually. A filter is a click on an element of a chart. I want to display all filters from multiple charts in one place. I will provide a jsfiddle to play around with shortly. To display a filter for each chart individually like in the link I provided  one has to put this

```
<span class="reset" style="display: none;"> | Current filter: <span class="filter"></span></span>
```

within the `<div>` of that chart like so

```
<div id="chart">
   <span class="reset" style="display: none;"> | Current filter: <span class="filter"></span></span>
</div>
```

I want to combine those filters in one place though outside the chart's div. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not directly supplied by dc.js. However you can read the `filters` property of each chart in order to get the current filters:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#filters-1

And you can listen for the filter changing using the "filtered" event:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#onfiltered-functionchart-filter

Hope that is enough to get you started! A PR would certainly be welcome.